# coronavirus - Why no 'c' capital? Why is there no space?

Tags: capitalization

It is written [*'coronavirus'* with no space and no capitalized 'c'](https://www.who.int/health-topics/coronavirus). I'm not sure about it. It is **the name** of virus which makes it a proper noun. Plus, they should be two words like other viruses have. The list is [here](https://www.livescience.com/56598-deadliest-viruses-on-earth.html) One of the known examples is ***Ebola virus.***

Comment: [rhinoviruses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+rhinoviruses%2Cof+Rhinoviruses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20rhinoviruses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20Rhinoviruses%3B%2Cc0) and [coronaviruses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+coronaviruses%2Cof+Coronaviruses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20coronaviruses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20Coronaviruses%3B%2Cc0) aren't usually capitalised, as those charts show..

Comment: I don’t think it’s so clear cut. I’ve seen Coronavirus with and without a space, capitalized and uncapitalized. I also think that Ebolavirus is a valid spelling (albeit rare), being the name of the genus.

Comment: ...think of it like ***estate car, saloon car*** (not capitalised, because they're relatively "generic" categories). Note that ***Covid 19*** (the *specific* type) is always capitalised.

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here between scientific terms and common names as well.  "coronavirus" is a scientific term for the family of viruses which includes the one which causes COVID-19.  "Ebola virus" is the common name for "the virus which causes the Ebola disease".  The scientific term for this group of viruses (there's actually several) is actually "ebolavirus" (no capitalization/space) as well.

Comment: Also note that "coronavirus" is a whole family of viruses, not just one.  It includes a wide variety of things, including many that have no effect on humans and several viruses which can cause the common cold.  The specific virus that causes the COVID-19 disease is named SARS-CoV-2 (or "SARS coronavirus 2")

Comment: See [related question on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233975/are-names-of-diseases-ever-capitalized)

Comment: "__COVID-19__" (properly all caps) is the abbreviation of the _disease_ fully described as "Coronavirus Disease 2019" or "Coronavirus disease 2019". The specific virus is SARS-CoV-2, short for "severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2" (no caps). If you aren't using all caps, it's _more_ common, not less, to use lowercase covid.

Comment: In your question you wrote "It is the name of virus" - that sentence is not grammatical (it should be either "a virus" or "the virus").  But, in fact, it is the name of a *class of viruses*, not a single virus.  It is merely a generic name of the SARS-CoV-2, in which a capital "C" *is* actually used.

Comment: The answers here are making it way more complicated than it needs to be: the vast vast majority of people (99.9%?) could care less about the technical details and use whatever feels natural. Even go through prestigious journals like nejm and you will see articles with Coronavirus, coronavirus, Novel Coronavirus, novel coronavirus and so on: https://www.nejm.org/coronavirus .  Language is fluid.

Answer (score 55):

The convention in English (and it may be different in other languages that use the Latin script) is that names of animals, plants and (by extension) viruses are not capitalised, unless part of the name comes from a proper noun.

So we have "blue tit" or "dog rose", but "Steller's sea eagle" and "African elephant" because Africa and Steller are the names of a continent and a person respectively. Ebola is capitalised as it is the name of a river in Africa (the Ebola river is a tributary of the Congo).

We also (again by convention) capitalise the *scientific* names of above the level of genus. So the blue tit is *Cyanistes caeruleus* in the family *Paridae* (the tit family) and the class *Aves* (birds).

Now "coronavirus" is not the scientific name (that is the subfamily *Orthocoronavirinae*). The particular one doing the rounds now is a *Betacoronavirus*. Instead "coronavirus" is the English name and so follows normal capitalisation for animals, plants and (by extension) viruses.

Names of viruses are often formed as single words with the suffix -virus. This is perhaps influenced by scientific use. There are rhinoviruses, noroviruses, adenovirus and so on. Again there isn't a logical rule, that is just how it is done. The virus that causes Ebola is known as ebolavirus (and note the downcasing when Ebola becomes a prefix).

Comment: And if the world had decided to stick with "Wuhan virus", then it would be two words with a capital W, like the Ebola virus.

Comment: The logical rule of all the common examples you gave is that virus is their root and there's a prefix that's being added. Some people compound two terms together (as ebolavirus) to make a single word. In any case, in neither case is virus actually a suffix.

Comment: Or its a compound,  however this is dancing on pinheads.

Comment: You might want to edit that actually "the coronavirus" is not even the name of that particular virus, but really a [_type_ of virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus). There are other coronaviruses, like the one causing (the 2003) SARS, and a couple of ones that just cause the common cold. Then again, [apparently there's also more than one virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebolavirus) causing the Ebola disease, so I'm not sure if that's accurate as a proper name either...

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your second to last paragraph.

Answer (score 19):

> It is written [*'coronavirus'* with no space and no capitalized 'c'][1]. I'm not sure about it. It is **the name** of virus which makes it a proper noun.

No, that's not the name of the virus. The name of the virus is SARS-CoV-2, and the name of the disease that the virus causes is COVID-19.

The word "coronavirus", on the other hand, is just a common noun. There are lots of different types of coronaviruses. The word "coronavirus" is a [classical compound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_compound) created in the 1960s, and like all classical compounds, it's a single word, written with no space.

SARS-CoV-2 is a type of coronavirus, and as a result, the virus and the disease are often called "the coronavirus". Calling the disease "the coronavirus" is perfectly fine, although it's somewhat imprecise.

However, in any case, "coronavirus" is definitely not the *name* of either the virus or the disease.

Comment: On the other hand language is used for communication and calling it "the coronavirus" is absolutely fine because only a handful of people care about these technical nuances.

Comment: @eps That's true. I've edited my answer to make it clearer that calling it "the coronavirus" is totally fine.

Comment: [XKCD wrote a comic strip about calling it "the coronavirus"](https://xkcd.com/2275/)

Answer (score 13):

As for the capitalization, coronavirus(es) is (are) actually more of a category than a single specific thing.  But at any rate, we do not capitalise *cold*, *influenza*, or *measles* either.  I'm not a biologist any more than I'm a linguist, so I apologise if this analogy is clunky - but I don't think of them as proper nouns, they are more like *cat* and *mouse* than *Tom* and *Jerry*.

(Ebola is named after the river, which *is* a proper noun, explaining why it is an apparent exception.)

As for the spacing, I'm not sure.  I don't think there is a clear cut norm.  I might suggest (with little to no evidence) that *-virus* is often/usually combined into a single word within scientific/medical terminology, like *retrovirus*, *norovirus*, *adenovirus* etc.  Perhaps this is especially likely when both or all parts of the compound word are Latin in origin.  (Note that *corona* is Latin for *crown*.)

Whereas two separate words is maybe more common with layman's terms / common names / mass media, and/or where the descriptive word or specific name is not Latin (as in Ebola virus - although that family, too, is called ebolaviruses in the scientific world).

Comment: I'm not a biologist either, but as far as I can tell, I think your analogy is very useful.

Answer (score 4):

[International Committee on Taxonomy of Viruses, FAQ #386 How to write
virus and species
names](https://talk.ictvonline.org/information/w/faq/386/how-to-write-virus-and-species-names):

> A **collective name** for a group of viruses belonging to a higher-level taxon is neither italicized nor capitalized, even if it was derived from a proper noun. The first letter of a collective name may be capitalized if it begins a sentence.
>
> - ourmiaviruses, ourmiavirus
> - Guernseyviruses are distributed worldwide.
> - The guernseyviruses are distributed worldwide.
> - aparaviruses
> - the aparavirus polymerase
>
> Note that if taxa have the same stem (e.g. *Flavivirus* and *Flaviviridae*), this may lead to ambiguity because both groups of viruses could be referred to as flaviviruses. Some virologists use the terms stem + virads, stem + virids, stem + virins, and stem + virus to distinguish members of orders, families, subfamilies and genera, respectively.
>
> **Complex example sentences**
>
> - Ebola virus (species *Zaire ebolavirus*; genus *Ebolavirus*; family  *Filoviridae*; order *Mononegavirales*) can cause disease in humans and nonhuman primates.
>
> ...
>
> * The complete rules for naming virus taxa can be found in the [ICTV Code](http://ictv.global/code).
>
> ** A proper noun is a name used for an individual person, place, or organization. A common noun denotes a class of objects or a concept. Host genus names are normally considered as proper nouns because they refer to a group of unique entities but some, for example "citrus", have become common nouns because they can also describe intergeneric hybrids. Virus genus names are not considered as proper nouns when used as part of a species or virus name because they refer to a subset of the genus and not the genus as a whole.

In the current case, "coronavirus" is the collective name for the
members of the family *Coronaviridae*; thus, "*Coronaviridae*" is
italicized and capitalized, but "coronavirus" isn't. Additionally
(see e.g.
[this](https://talk.ictvonline.org/information/w/news/1300/page)), the
(official) virus name "severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus
2" is not italicized, but the species name (scientific name) "*Severe
acute respiratory syndrome-related coronavirus*" is italicized.

---

In the case of the Ebola virus, "Ebola" is the **proper** name of a
tributary of the Congo River near which the first case was isolated, so
"Ebola" retains capitalization; for the species name "*Zaire
ebolavirus*" however, only "Zaire" is capitalized (as a **proper**
name), and "ebolavirus" being the species name is left uncapitalized.

Taxonomical nomenclature is straightforward if you know the rules.

(This should probably have been a question for biology.SE.)

Comment: I'd say this is more a question of [english.se] than [biology.se], even though they do have a [terminology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag. The description says "How terms are used or the meaning of words as used in scientific literature." which does not include spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some context to the other answers about spaces...
Likely because of English's diverse origins, it has an ambiguous relationship with compound words. Compound words are where smaller words are joined together into larger single words, instead of keeping them separated with a space. English is actually a Germanic language with a lot of Latin vocabulary. Both these languages naturally use compound words. While we do this in English a bit, usually with only 2 compounds, like "cannot" or "become", Germanic languages generally do this for most words. From German, there is "Abbaugerechtigkeit" with 3 parts, as well as Swedish's "parkeringsgarage".

Instead of having compound words be systematic, like in other Germanic languages, English seems to only add compound words to the language after decades of use and there are [differences between American (AmE) and British English (BrE) in this respect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Word_derivation_and_compounds). Thus, my experience as a native English speaker has been that it is not at all clear when two words can be used as a single word or not. Luckily, there is a nice solution.

In American English at least, usually you can combine two words with a hyphen '-', like "part-time". The [rules for hyphen use](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/) extend far beyond nouns. The hyphen is also nice for English students, because it clearly identifies where the words break apart, a bit like Japanese (自殺).

As both previous answers hinted at, there is no space between "corona" and "virus" because most scientific words are in Latin.

Comment: I can't find 問亭 in my dictionary; is it a proper name?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll use a better example. Didn't want to get too off-topic, but wanted to show how unique the way English handled compound nouns was.

Comment: "Abbaugerechtigkeit" is very harmless for a German compound

Comment: "Harmless", like short? I simply went to Wiktionary's list of German compounds and found the first word composed of 3 smaller words. English also has some famously long compounds, but the point is to demonstrate trends in the language, not exceptions - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_compound_words @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 0):

The genus of viruses that cause "Ebola virus disease" (with spaces) is in fact called *ebolavirus* (no space).  Likewise, *coronavirus* (no space) refers to members of the family of viruses that cause "corona virus disease" (with spaces).  That last term, of course, gets abbreviated to CoViD.

Side note:  *coronavirus* is a less-specific name than *ebolavirus*. It refers to members of the family *coronaviridae* (meaning crown-shaped viruses) or its sub-family *Orthocoronavirinae*.   A family/sub-family is slightly higher up the taxonomic tree than a genus.  Analogously, the genus *ebolavirus* is part of the family *filoviridae* meaning string-shaped viruses.